# The difference betweem RFM12S and RFM12B

Tags: avr, wireless

I want develop a board, which should use a wireless interface to send data. I have the RFM12S module and I find only docs about the RFM12B! does anybody know the difference between those two !

Comment: Details of the RFM12B? Have you tried the supplier?

Comment: This may be useful reading  http://jeelabs.org/2009/05/06/rfm12-vs-rfm12b-revisited/

Answer (score 1):

The RFM12 appears to use this Silicon Labs chip Si4420. https://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/Si4420.pdf

The board supplier, HopeRF , does not report any S version.
http://www.hoperf.com/rf/module/fsk/

Only RFM12B and ...BP version.